# Configure Barracuda Spam Filter behind Postfix to use client IP when do RBL-checking

Tags: postfix, spam, barracuda, rbl

I have the following setup:

Internet -> Postfix Mail setup as Proxy -> Barracuda Spam Filter -> Microsoft Exchange

I have tried searching through the documentation and configuration panels to see how I could get the Barracuda to use the original client IP to compare against black lists. I could not find anything related to mail proxies before the Barracuda.

Is there any way to configure either my Postfix relay or the Barracuda so that the Barracuda can see and use the original client IP as the origin of the email?

My initial guess is I would have to set a header, sort of like using nginx as a web proxy. e.g. X-ORIGINAL-IP or the like, but I am unsure what I would have to set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the Barracuda **"Deep-Header Scan"** feature. Depending on your unit and firmware revision, it's likely masked under the `IP Configuration` > `Trusted Forwarder` setting.

> Trusted Forwarder Configuration
>
> Enter the IP addresses of machines
>   that you have set up to forward email (i.e. Trusted Forwarders) to the
>   Barracuda Spam & Virus Firewall from outside sources. The Barracuda
>   Spam & Virus Firewall exempts any IP address in this list from Rate
>   Control, SPF checks and IP Reputation. In the Received headers, the
>   Barracuda Spam & Virus Firewall will continue looking beyond a Trusted
>   Forwarder IP address until it encounters the first non-trusted IP
>   address. At this point, Rate Control, SPF checks and IP Reputation
>   checks will be applied.

This used to be a separate feature, but in the v5.1 changelog, Barracuda removed it from the UI:

> Mail Processing
>
> The Deep Header Scan setting for use with Trusted Forwarder IP
>   addresses has been removed from the web interface, as this
>   functionality is now part of the Trusted Forwarder feature.

---

[image]

Comment: By the way, Barracuda hid the feature in the UI because it used to block people sending from home addresses (on consumer broadband) and mobile phone carriers. Yours is the only use case where it makes sense to do a **DEEP** scan because of your proxy server.